# What library do I have to use to use ComparatorChain and addComparator?

Tags: java, comparator

My professor gave me an assignment on sorting books and videos. This is the test code she gave it to me. But I am really confused about which library to use for comparatorchain. I just can't get it to work. I tried to import java.util.Comparator but it just doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ComparatorChain chain = new ComparatorChain();
Database library = new Database();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(1890, Calendar.AUGUST, 10);
Date date = (Date) cal.getTime();
library.addItem(new Textbook("TB15", "TextX", date, "John Doe"));
cal.set(1954, Calendar.JANUARY, 18);
date = (Date) cal.getTime() ;
library.addItem(new Textbook("TB01", "TextY", date, "John Doe"));
chain.addComparator(new SortByTitle());
chain.addComparator(new SortByAddedOn());
chain.addComparator(new SortByDirector());
Collections.sort(library.item, chain);
library.list();}`
```

Comment: Where exactly did you get this code from? What library/JAR file did they say you should include in your project?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the `ComparatorChain` class is from the Apache commons library. You can see the documentation [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparatorChain.html). You can also download the jar [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.3).